# Динамические элементы в json c# winforms

Tags: c#, json

Для сериализации в json использую newtonsoft. Мне надо сделать один такой раздел так, чтобы при нажатии кнопки появлялись два новых textbox(сколько угодно раз) и эти данные записывались в один.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот в этом блоке isp может быть сколько угодно name и ipaddress(наши появляющиеся дополнительно по нажатию кнопки). Можно ли это сделать?

Comment: Можно. В чем конкретно проблема? Вы не знаете как добавить контролы на форму? Или не знаете как добавить элементы в массив в json?

Comment: И контролы,которые были добавлены в результате работы  и элементы(

Comment: Ну вы про массивы/списки знаете же? Вот храните ссылки на контролы в массиве.

Comment: Да знаю, скоро попробую

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, Вам нужно создать класс и сериализовать его экземпляр в JSON. Для приведённого JSON класс может выглядеть следующим образом:

```cs
public class Isp {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<System.Net.IPAddress> IPAddresses { get; set; }
}

public class Config {
    public List<Isp> Isp { get; set; }
}
```

Далее просто сериализируете экземпляр класса Config в JSON и при необходимости создаёте экземпляр Config из JSON. Ниже приведены примеры сериализации и десериализации:

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

public static class NewtonsoftUtils {

    public static T Deserialize<T>(string path) => Deserialize<T>(path, Encoding.UTF8, 65536, true);
    public static T Deserialize<T>(string path, Encoding encoding, int bufferSize, bool detectEncodingFromBOM) {

        // Размер буфера 64К дает гораздо лучшую производительность, чем 
        // размер буфера по умолчанию 4K.Его можно увеличить еще больше, 
        // но было обнаружено, что дальнейшее увеличение буфера не дает 
        // существенного прироста в производительности, а на некоторых 
        // системах может привести и к ее снижению.
        int bs = bufferSize > 65536 || bufferSize < 0
            ? 65536
            : bufferSize;

        bool det = detectEncodingFromBOM;
        string content = string.Empty;

        using (var sr = new StreamReader(path, encoding, det, bs)) {
            content = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(content);
    }

    public static void Serialize(object obj, string path) => Serialize(obj, path, Encoding.UTF8, 65536);
    public static void Serialize(object obj, string path, int bufferSize) => Serialize(obj, path, Encoding.UTF8, bufferSize);
    public static void Serialize(object obj, string path, Encoding encoding, int bufferSize) {

        Encoding enc = encoding ?? Encoding.UTF8;
        // Размер буфера 64К дает гораздо лучшую производительность, чем 
        // размер буфера по умолчанию 4K.Его можно увеличить еще больше, 
        // но было обнаружено, что дальнейшее увеличение буфера не дает 
        // существенного прироста в производительности, а на некоторых 
        // системах может привести и к ее снижению.
        int bs = bufferSize > 65536 || bufferSize < 0
            ? 65536
            : bufferSize;

        var serializer = new JsonSerializer {
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented
        };

        Directory.CreateDirectory(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path));

        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(path, false, enc, bs))
        using (var tw = new JsonTextWriter(sw)) {
            //TODO: NullValueHandling add to parameters
            // serializer.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
            serializer.Serialize(tw, obj);
        }
    }
}

// пример использования
NewtonsoftUtils.Serialize(configInstance, path);
Config config = NewtonsoftUtils.Deserialize<Config>(path);
```

Для решения Вашей задачи необходимо создать форму создания экземпляра Isp, где для Isp.Name Вы можете использовать TextBox, а для Isp.IPAddresses - ListBox. После создания экземпляра Isp добавляете его в Config.Isp и сериализируете в JSON.

Comment: А можно пример, как привязать новые textbox, созданные в процессе работы уже к коду?

Comment: @PavelKutsubin посмотрите в сторону Binding, DataSource и BindingList. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/winforms/multiple-controls-bound-to-data-source-synchronized, https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-share-bound-data-across-forms-using-the-bindingsource-component

Comment: а мы можем перейти в чат?( У меня ругается на последние две строчки

Comment: @PavelKutsubin https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91702/ru-stackoverflow-com-questions-962732

Comment: @PavelKutsubin ссылка на пример: https://www.dropbox.com/s/txpba2ilvprv8uw/JsonExample.zip?dl=0